# The function writeValueWithoutResponse to write data to a BLE pheripheral doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to communicate via chrome with a BLE device and I'm following along with this video:

https://youtu.be/XDc5HUVMI5U?t=1023

Everything works until he says to use the method:

`characteristic.writeValue(new Uint8Array[ 0x00,r, g,b ]);`

I looked it up and it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic/writeValue

Instead you should use:

`characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(new Uint8Array[ 0x00,r, g,b ]);`

The problem is that this doesn't work either. It says:

*script.js:29 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.setupBLE (script.js:29)*

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Here's all my code so far:

````
button.onclick = setupBLE;
let options = {
filters: [
{ services: ['19b10000-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214'] },
{ name: 'Stepper motor control' }
]
};
async function setupBLE() {
console.log("test");
let device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options);
let server = await device.gatt.connect();
let service = await server.getPrimaryService("19b10000-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214");

//Same name but with 19b10001 instead of 19b10000
let characteristic = service.getCharacteristic("19b10001-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214");
console.log(characteristic);
characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(new Uint8Array([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]));
}```
````

Comment: `service.getCharacteristic()`returns a promise so maybe you need to use `await service.getCharacteristic()` like you did in the lines above

Comment: Yeah I saw that after posting but that didn't fix it. I'm starting to think that I need to include a checksum or something. I tried reading from the BLE peripheral and that worked fine. The peripheral itself is an Arduino Nano IoT.

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue as me just use the method writeValueWithoutResponse instead and it will magically work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `service.getCharacteristic()` returns a promise, you have to use `await` there. Note that `writeValueWithoutResponse` also returns a promise.

```js
const characteristicUuid = "19b10001-e8f2-537e-4f6c-d104768a1214";
const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid);

const value = new Uint8Array([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);
await characteristic.writeValueWithoutResponse(value);

console.log("wrote value to characteristic");
```

You can find more documentation at https://web.dev/bluetooth/#write